# How to tell visual studio that i have installed visual C# too?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I got visual studio 2005 express edition installed on my machine.But it did not contain any C# or web developer with it. So i later installed visual C# too. Now , I can create a C# project through visual C#. But I cant use visual studio for the same purpose. I guess there would be some mechanism to integrate visual C# with visual studio. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition" there is only Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition, Visual C# 2005 Express Edition and so on. You cannot "integrate" the Express Editions they are all separate.

Comment: oops! there was a mistake. It is visual studio 2005, not visual studio 2005 express edition. I have previously been using visual studio 2005 to create all kind of applications viz. console applications, web applications, windows forms applications. Problem is that I am not able to do the same on my new machine.